# How to find recent date from date field in MongoDb?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB Collection in which there is one date field.I want to find the latest date from date field.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a `mongoose.Model`, you can do it doing a `find` like this:

```
Model.find()
.sort({ dateField: -1 })
.limit(1)
```